# Issue with displaying payment method logos in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to replace the names of payment methods in WooCommerce with their corresponding logos using a custom function. However, when I add the function to my code, the images are not displayed as expected. Instead, the alt text is shown. Here is the function I am using:

```
function replace_card_type_with_logo($card_type) {
$card_type = strtolower($card_type);

$card_logos = array(
'visa' => 'http://symbiosewear.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/visa.png',
'mastercard' => 'http://symbiosewear.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/mastercard.png',
'amex' => 'http://symbiosewear.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/amex.png',
);

if (isset($card_logos[$card_type])) {
$card_logo = $card_logos[$card_type];
return '<img src="' . $card_logo . '" alt="' . $card_type . '">';
}

return wp_kses_post($card_type);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_credit_card_type_label', 'replace_card_type_with_logo');
```

The image URLs provided in the $card_logos array are correct, as I can access them directly from the browser. However, when the function is applied, the images are not displayed, and instead, the alt text is shown.

I have also provided a screenshot of the output in the question:

[image]

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: You can't use `woocommerce_get_credit_card_type_label` filter hook to add payment card icons, as it's using behind `esc_htm()` on the related WooCommerce template files. So you need to make changes in those related templates to make it possible.

Comment: You can use woocommerce_gateway_icon filter which holds $icon - the path and $id the payment method there are many examples - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723517/add-an-icon-to-custom-woocommerce-payment-gateway